# Adding certificates to Mono certificate stores Trust but doesn't work

Tags: linux, ssl, mono

I have a code to download the xml from the url like  https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esummary.fcgi?db=pubmed&rettype=abstract&id=27160201&retmax=1000&retmode=xml

Since mono trust store is empty when initialized, I went to the site, downloaded the root CA, and use certmgr to add it to mono.

> certmgr -add -c -m Trust DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.cer

Now I can see the certificate under ~/.configure/.mono/cert/ski-B13EC36903F8BF4701D498261A0802EF63642BC3.cer, the hash is same as the root CA.

However, I still can't access the file. It comes with the same error "The authentication or decryption has failed".

Any suggestions or did I miss sth there?

Comment: What version of Mono are you using? and if using 4.8+ are you setting `MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls`?

Comment: @SushiHangover: for some historical reason, I am using mono 2.10.9